# css positioning - cant see ont of the icons

Tags: css

i have some problems with the CSS code below. The problem is that only one of the icons are visible (#maps), guess it is some problem with the positioning? (70%?) i cant find the problem, hope that someone here can help.
Thanks in advance.

```
#navlist {
    position: relative;
}

#navlist li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
left: 70%;
}

#navlist li, #navlist a {
    height: 64px;
    display: block;
}

#face{
left: 0px;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background: url('.../imageurl') 0 0;
}

#maps{

    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background: url('.../imageurl') 0  0;
}
```

Html code:

```
<ul id="navlist">
  <li id="face"><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li id="maps"><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can just do a quick check and give #face:
       position:absolute; left:0; top:0; z-index:10; If you still cant see it, it has nothing to do with the positioning.

Comment: @davedadizzel 
now i can see the face icon, seems like it appears over the maps icon.

Comment: yes it does! Now we know its a positioning issue. I will have a look at the HTML and answer again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is definetly an issue with #face! Although I´m not sure if that will make it visible again because I would also need your HTML code. You gave it the attribute left:0px; (btw. you dont need to write "px" if it is 0 anyways). But the browser cant do anything with that because it doesnt know with which kind of positioning you are working! The attribute left:0; makes only sense if you have already given it either position:absolute; or position:relative;. All over all I would advise you to read more about the basic position techniques and upload you HTML for a closer look.

EDIT: Found the problem.You think #face has the attribute left:0;? You are wrong! Because #navlist li { left:70%} beats #face{left:0;} So just remove that attribute at #navlist li and add it at #maps! It will fix it! It was a cascading issue if you are want to read more about it google: CSS cascading system.

Comment: html is in the main post.